# Stacks: Balanced Brackets Hacker Rank

Tags: c#, interview-questions, balanced-delimiters

Here is the general goal of this exercise:

> For each string, print whether or not the string of brackets is balanced on a new line. If the brackets are balanced, print YES; otherwise, print NO.

Please comment as this was a job interview and I had 30 mins to give something working and the best performance wise.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace JobInterviewTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            List<string> list = new List<string> {"({[]})", "][(]}})("};

            foreach (var barcketsList in list)

            {
                string expression = barcketsList;
                Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
                char[] symbols = expression.ToCharArray();
                if (symbols.Length == 0)
                {   
                    break;
                }
                bool flagPrint = false;
                for (int start = 0; start < symbols.Count(); start++)
                {
                    char temp = symbols[start];
                    if (temp == '[' || temp == '{' || temp == '(')
                    {
                        stack.Push(temp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (stack.Count == 0) //only closer no opening
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("NO");
                            flagPrint = true;
                            break;

                        }
                        char top = stack.Peek();
                        if (temp == ']')
                        {
                            if (top != '[')
                            {   
                                break;
                            }
                            stack.Pop();
                        }
                        else if (temp == '}')
                        {
                            if (top != '{')
                            {

                                break;
                            }
                            stack.Pop();
                        }
                        else // temp == ')'
                        {
                            if (top != '(')
                            {

                                break;
                            }
                            stack.Pop();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!stack.Any() && !flagPrint)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("YES");
                }
                else if (!flagPrint)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NO");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, this code is nearly incomprihensible with such confusing variable names.

Comment: @t3chb0t I had 30 mins to write it, so me and the interviewer we were fine with those names. but please review it if you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Let's look at the code first

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "({[]})", "][(]}})(" };
```

- Poor choice of variable name. You picked `expression` just a little below, that is a good one. Why not use the plural form of it: `expressions`?

```
foreach (var barcketsList in list)
```

- `barcketsList` contains a typo, not a big deal usually. However, you should pay some more attention for an interview.
- `bracket-s` + `List` you really don't want hinting this is an array/collection/list twice.

```
foreach (var barcketsList in list)
// <- unnecessary white line
{
```

- Don't leave white line just anywhere within a method in your code. They should be used to divide the logical blocks, eg: declaration/initialization vs logic vs return, logic#1 vs logic#2

```
string expression = barcketsList;
Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
char[] symbols = expression.ToCharArray();
```

- A temporary variable `expression` is not necessary here. In fact, both this and `barcketsList` is only used once. You can substitute one by the other.
- Use `var` when you can, it makes the variable names aligned thus making scanning easier. The variable name itself or its right-hand side assignment should give enough clue usually, plus you can always mouse-over with intellisense.

```
for (int start = 0; start < symbols.Count(); start++)
{
    char temp = symbols[start];
```

- Since you are just using the index (`start`) to get the char, you can use a `foreach`-loop here

```
if (stack.Count == 0) //only closer no opening
{
    Console.WriteLine("NO");
    flagPrint = true;
    break;
```

- The use of `flagPrint` here to escape the default final output is a bit more of a hack. For instance, since you are using `stack.Any()` to check for balance, you can push the closing bracket and `break` out of the loop to achieve the same behavior. You can also take an another approach and extract a `IsBalanced` out of existing code and use `return`.

```
if (!stack.Any() && !flagPrint)
{
    Console.WriteLine("YES");
}
else if (!flagPrint)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NO");
}
```

- If we were to keep the flag, this part can be reduced to:

  ```
  if (!flagPrint)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(!stack.Any() ? "YES" : "NO");
  }
  ```

### What is not in the code

- `IsBalanced` is not in a separated method.
- Lack of argument checking/error handling

### Solution

```
public void CheckAllExpressionsAreBalanced()
{
    var expressions = new List<string> { "({[]})", "][(]}})(" };
    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Expression `{0}` {1} balanced.",
        //    expression,
        //    IsBalanced(expression) ? "is" : "is not");
        Console.WriteLine(IsBalanced(expression) ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public bool IsBalanced(string expression)
{
    // argument validation
    if (expression == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));

    // definition
    var brackets = new[] { "()", "{}", "[]" };
    var pairedBrackets = brackets.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);

    // non-bracket characters doesn't affect the result,
    // so we can filter them out to make the flow simpler
    Func<char, bool> isBracket = c => pairedBrackets.ContainsKey(c) || pairedBrackets.ContainsValue(c);

    // implementation
    var stack = new Stack<char>();
    foreach (var c in expression.Where(isBracket))
    {
        var isOpening = pairedBrackets.ContainsKey(c);
        var pair = isOpening
            ? pairedBrackets[c]
            : pairedBrackets.First(x => x.Value == c).Key;

        if (isOpening)
        {
            stack.Push(c);
        }
        else
        {
            // closing bracket with empty stack
            if (!stack.Any())
                return false;

            // closing bracket doesnt match last opening bracket
            if (stack.Peek() != pair)
                return false;

            // matched
            stack.Pop();
        }
    }

    return !stack.Any();
}
```

EDIT: I skipped the requirements...
EDIT2: Updated `IsBalanced` to accept non-bracket characters input. As @HenrikHansen points out, it doesn't make sense to throw an exception.
EDIT3: Fixed issue with trailing brackets.

Comment: Why do you only allow brackets in the expressions?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Thank you so much for a great review

Comment: @HenrikHansen It is there so avoid checking for non-bracket characters in the for-loop, and validation for the sake of validation. Now, that I look at it, it does seem ill-fitted to consider presence of other characters as exception.

Comment: @Xiaoy312: OK, about the non-bracket chars. Another problem is that your solution can't handle a pattern like `"([]())("` correctly, because you don't check for an empty stack at the end of the `IsBalanced() {...}` method.

Comment: @HenrikHansen Good catch. I can't believe I made a such mistake.